# Are pre-order, in-order and post-order the only traversals for depth-first search?

Tags: trees, binary-trees, depth-first-search

With a binary tree, the 3 approaches for the tree below are listed.

```
    A
  /  \
B      C
Inorder   => Left, Root, Right.     - B, A, C
Preorder  => Root, Left, Right.     -  A, B, C
Post order=> Left, Right, Root.     -  B, C, A
```

I drew this up to get a better understanding because I thought of permutations with 3 elements would give `3! = 6`. However, I didn't see these other traversal orders mentioned online. Why is it this the case?

For example, if we wanted to get the reverse order of a binary search tree, could we not have the traversal `C, A, B` instead of doing in order and then flipping the output?

Comment: You can traverse the tree in any way you want depending on the requirement.

Comment: Are there names for these orders?

Comment: I do not think so. It is just a name. So doesn't matter much. :)